# x86 hw: String declaration, $ on numbers between -1000 & 1000?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have two questions about this homework assignment:

---

Write an assembly language program in a file called HW5.asm that would read in a signed base 10 number from the keyboard (less than 1000 and greater than -1000 ends with a $ sign) and calculates the square of the number and prints back to display. Since we are using Visual Studio emulator and there is no I/O you will have to create a string variable as the input and write a string to memory as the output.

---

A. How large should a string variable be? WORD string?

B. What does the professor mean by "ends with a $ sign"? Is that true? How do I remove that in order to read the number in properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. The string variable will be as long as needed to hold the string in question; given the specs, WORD won't be big enough.

B. Since you're the one writing the code to compute the numeric value represented by a string, you can use the $ as it was intended: to signify the end of the string.

Comment: With regards to B, how do you compare chars in x86? I've never read in a string before; all work was with simple ints. I understand the logic of [read char. if char is $, stop.] but I don't know how to check if it's $. OH cmp with hex codes, right?

Comment: You should be able to express the value of the character code directly; for example, cmp al, '0'.  And it'll come in handily to know that the character codes for the digits are in order, so a simple subtraction can get the numeric value of a digit character.

Comment: I would be much obliged if you would reword that last sentence in a way a total x86 beginner could more easily understand.

Comment: You should be able to express the character code for, say the character Zero, as just '0'.

Comment: The character codes for 0..9 are in the same over as the digits.  Thus, to compute the value represented by a digit from its character code, you only need to do a single subtraction.

Comment: What am I subtracting? My understanding of what you're saying is that '8's character code is 8, '7' is 7, etc. So to successfully deduce that '5's value is 5, I would subtract...?

Comment: Suppose that the character code for '0' were X; what would you subtract from that to get 0?  Assuming (correctly) that the codes for the other digits go up as the digits do, what do you get by performing that same subtraction on them?

Comment: ...subtract X? But '0' is 0, if I've understood, so...subtract zero each time?

Comment: '0' isn't 0, it's X, so, yes, subtract X.  You don't need to know what X is, the assembler does: whenever you use '0', the assembler will use the value X.  SO it may look a little weird, but you'd subtract '0'.